# Creation of Hashtable table in JMeter generating syntax error

Tags: java, jmeter

I need soome help to understand why I can't create a Hashtable object in JMeter.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;

Hashtable mqProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
mqProps.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "my_channel");
mqProps.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, my_port);
mqProps.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "my_host");
mqProps.put(MQConstants.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "my_user_id");
mqProps.put(MQConstants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "my_password");

MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("my_QM", mqProps);

vars.putObject("QMGR", qMgr);
```

Please find below error messages I'm facing:

```
ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script Create QueueManager, message: javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Hashtable; import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager; import com.ibm.mq. . . . '' Encountered "<" at line 7, column 34.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Hashtable; import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager; import com.ibm.mq. . . . '' at line number 7
javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Hashtable; import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager; import com.ibm.mq. . . . '' Encountered "<" at line 7, column 34.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Hashtable; import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager; import com.ibm.mq. . . . '' at line number 7
```

Do you have any idea why JMeter is not supporting `<` char ?

Note that Language is set as `java`.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that Language is set as java.

it is not Java, it's [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) which doesn't support [diamond operators](https://www.baeldung.com/java-diamond-operator) so the options are in:

- either remove them, i.e.  `Hashtable mqProps = new Hashtable();`
- or (better) switch to `groovy` as [it's recommended scripting option since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because [it provides better performance than any other language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)